# How to handle switching between two Python scripts?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, batch-file, multiprocessing

I have two separate Python scripts and one main script:

scriptA.py
scriptB.py
main.py

I want to run scripA.py from 5am to 12am and scriptB from 12am to 5pm. I want to write a script to do this for me. Currently I was trying to do this through main.py. But nothing is working at all. What I actually want is something like this.

```
if time betwee 5am and 12am:
    if scriptB running:
        stop scriptB
        execute scriptA
    else:
        execute scriptA
if time between 12:01am and 4:99:
    if scriptA running:
        stop scriptA
        execute scriptB
    else:
        execute scriptB
```

And if you have any other suggestion to achieve the above mentioned functionality please tell me.

Comment: what operating system are you running on? Does it have to be a python script or is calling a function from another script ok? Can you provide more info on what your scripts look like or do?

Comment: Unless you REALLY need a main script, I would use a task scheduling utility (Unix: Cron, Windows: Task Scheduler, OS X: Launchd, etc.) to run scripts A and B during the appropriate time windows.

Comment: @rbierman OS:linux .. My main script which is a python script is calling two other scripts not just a function. whole scripts. one scriptA is doing face detection and scriptB is doing motion detection.

Comment: @apollo2020 can tell me more about cron. can i switch between two scripts according to specific time using cron ? my os is linux.

Comment: @irumzahra, hover your mouse over the batch-file tag and read the description.

Comment: Starting a script is easy, stopping it properly requires cooperation. Functionally, that means that you must identify a place in the script where it can see whether is should stop or go on. Once this is done, you either have it to consistently stop the scripts at that place and have a monitor that restarts the appropriate script, or set up an interprocess communication way (presence of file, signal, event or any IPC) way by which the monitor asks the currently running script to stop. But your question is way too broad to give a detailed answer.

Comment: @irumzahra Yes, you can create jobs that only run during a specific time-window: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea that is untested and would appreciate feedback. The general idea is to check which program to run based on the current time and then wait until the time-switch.

CODE:

```
from datetime import datetime 
import subprocess
import sys

def check_time():
    script_type = ''
    wait_time = None
    now = datetime.now()
    if 5 <= now.hour <= 23:
        script_type = 'ScriptA'
        end_time = now.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999)
        wait_time = end_time-now
    elif 0 <= now.hour <= 4:
        script_type = 'ScriptB'
        end_time = now.replace(hour=3, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999)
        wait_time = end_time-now

    return script_type,wait_time.seconds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    active_process = None

    #Loop forever
    while True:

        #If there is an active process, terminate it
        if active_process:
            active_process.terminate()
            active_process.kill()

        #Start the correct script
        script_type,wait_time = check_time()
        if script_type == 'ScriptA':
            active_process = subprocess.Popen([YOUR,COMMAND,A,HERE])
        elif script_type == 'ScriptB':
            active_process = subprocess.Popen([YOUR,COMMAND,B,HERE])
        else:
            sys.stderr.write('Some sort of error\n')
            sys.exit(1)

        #Wait until the next time switch to loop again
        time.sleep(wait_time)
```

Please comment any questions or let me know if it works if you've tried to implement it.